# Code first One way many to many relationship using data annotation

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two models in my application: `Stock` and `Report`. A report can have many stocks and a stock can be used in many reports.

```
public enum ElectionType 
{
    MANAGER =1 , 
    INSPECTOR , 
    BOTH
}
public class Report
{
    public Report()
    {
        Stocks = new List<Stock>();
    }

    public int ReportID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ShamsiDate { get; set; }

    public int? StockID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public  ElectionType  ElectionType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StockID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set;}
}
public class Stock
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StockID { get; set; }
    public int FinancialCode { get; set; }
    public String NationalCode { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String FatherName { get; set; }
    public String Place { get; set; }

    public int StockCount { get; set; }

    public int StockPrice { get; set; }
    public int StockSize { get; set; }

    public int StartStock { get; set; }

    public int EndStock { get; set; }

}
```

I want to create a one way relationship so there is no way to access a `Report` from a `Stock`. I have written this code but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should point out the code you *think* does this, and why you think it "doesn't work." What output are you expecting based on what input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with annotations you will need a junction table:

```
public class ReportStock
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int StockID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReportID")]
    public virtual Report Report { get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("StockID")]
    public virtual Stock Stock { get; set;}
}
```

Then change your Report class:

```
public class Report
{
    public Report()
    {
        ReportStocks = new List<ReportStock>();
    }

    public int ReportID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ShamsiDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public  ElectionType  ElectionType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ReportStock> ReportStocks { get; set;}
}
```